# minimum photo size allowed to upload?

Tags: php, upload

I read some **experts/masters** advices on the net says that: *Set a minimum file size(photo) to upload, if it is too small, it can cause a DDOS*. But they don't mentioned there what *atleast* is the minimum file size allowed. So that's my question. Whats is your answer? Thanks!

Comment: Strange "advice"... You can use _any_ request for a DDOS. So what is the point in that?

Comment: I guess it's just one of the thousand options for exploiting a request for DDOS purposes. If the file is too small, many files could be uploaded very often. But probably the whole solution includes other anti-spam mechanisms like setting the frequency of uploading new files, good authorization before uploading, all kinds of client side verification that it's a proper image file, etc.

Comment: i think i read that at owasp, i will search it again. `galya` is quite right, thanks for the both of you, i will search for anti-spam instead.

Answer (score 1):

Many sites still use transparent 1-pixel GIFs to track data. I'm looking at one now that is literally 17 bytes in length. So really, there is no real answer to this question, other than "What you think is best".

Ask yourself what the minimum size WxH photo you'll allow is, then render yourself a pure white low quality JPG with those dimensions and look at the file size. This wouldn't be very useful, however, as people can still saturate your network connection by uploading very large uploads, or tapping away at any other part of your website with a botnet to achieve an attack anyway. Plus, you're likely to misjudge the minimum file size and end up blocking legitimate users with a false positive sooner or later.

Comment: thanks, do you have some sample or links etc ? it really helps me thanks

Comment: @phew Please keep in mind that asking for off-site resources is considered [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow, as those types of answers are likely to attract spam, and links may go dead resulting in less information for future visitors. :) Happy asking!